# Class cast exception in JWT

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt

I am creating a token string using `JwtBuilder`. But while extracting a value using a key, it is giving `ClassCastException`. For better understanding code snippet are provided below:

**Token creation:**

```
private JwtBuilder getJwtBuilder(
        String jti,
        Long issuedAt,
        Long expiredAt,
        Long businessAccountId,
        Long consumerAccountId,
        String deviceId
) {
    JwtBuilder builder = Jwts.builder();
    builder.setIssuer("SO");
    builder.setSubject(TokenConstant.TOKEN_SUBJECT);
    builder.setId(jti);
    builder.setIssuedAt(new Date(issuedAt));
    builder.setExpiration(new Date(expiredAt));
    builder.claim(TokenConstant.BUSINESS_ACCOUNT_ID, businessAccountId);
    builder.claim(TokenConstant.DEVICE_ID, deviceId);
    builder.signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, secretKey);
    return builder;
}
```

**Decoding token:**

```
private JsonWebToken decodeToken(String jsonWebToken) {
    try {
        Jws<Claims> map = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secretKey).parseClaimsJws(jsonWebToken);
        Claims claims = map.getBody();
        return getJsonWebTokenFromClaims(claims);
    } catch (SignatureException | MalformedJwtException e) {
        throw new InvalidTokenException(e.getMessage());
    }
}

private JsonWebToken getJsonWebTokenFromClaims(Claims claims) {
    JsonWebToken token = new JsonWebToken();
    token.jti = claims.getId();
    token.expirationTime = claims.getExpiration().getTime();
    token.issuedAt = claims.getIssuedAt().getTime();
    token.deviceId = (String) claims.get(TokenConstant.DEVICE_ID);
    token.businessAccountId =  (Long) claims.get(TokenConstant.BUSINESS_ACCOUNT_ID);
    return token;
}
```

**Exception:**

> 2018-04-23 10:27:04.476  ERROR b.c.i.s.c.MyExceptionHandler -
>   Application error: {} java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer
>   cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

**jwt version:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
    <version>0.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

As you can see that my code is getting an error while casting `Integer` type value to a `Long` type. I am unable to understand, why `Object` type is converted to `Integer` implicitly?

Comment: Please post your code directly instead of screenshots, it's quite cumbersome to click on 4 links to see your code. Kindly read [Ask]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest upgrading the version of your jwt dependency to version `0.9.0`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The issue was reported here as [an issue in Github](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt/issues/142) which indicates the auto binding to the data type based on smaller values set as a claim. I am copying the exact statement from the issue to elaborate more.

```
  String claimName = "long"
  Long claimVal = new Long(5)
  String compact = Jwts.builder().setClaims([(claimName): claimVal]).compact();
  Claims claims = Jwts.parser().parse(compact).body as Claims
  // `claims.get` throws `RequiredTypeException`
  assert claims.get(claimName, Long) == claimVal
```

> Here, Jackson finds that a 5 is small enough to fit in the Integer and
>   so unmarshalls into it, instead of expected Long.
>
> What makes matters worse is that when a value is large enough (≥
>   2^31), Jackson will switch to Long and so code that naively always
>   get()-s Integer will stop working:

However, the issue has been fixed in [this pull request](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt/pull/172) and is available in the newer released version of the jwt library.

After updating the library you can get the proper value without having a `RequiredTypeException` using the following code.

```
// businessAccountId is declared as Long I guess
token.businessAccountId = claims.get(TokenConstant.BUSINESS_ACCOUNT_ID, Long.class);
```

Hope that fixes your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Token creation file 3rd line from bottom you are doing ".longvalue()".
I think you should try to change type of field "business AccountId"to Long

Comment: What does builder.claim 4 th line from bottom in Token creation file expects. You just need to pass that type og arguement.

Comment: Latest code and error is pasted.
builder.claim() is nothing but a map of <string,object>. So, it doesn't matter what type of value I put there.